# equalTo in Firebase finding nothing

Tags: android, firebase

I'm having a database with articles and want to get the article(s) that match a category see the data structure here: [Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/283T4.png)

Here is my code,

```
    Query queryRef = ref.orderByChild("categories").equalTo("Sjukdomar");
    queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild)  {

        Log.d("Answer:  ",snapshot.getValue().toString());
        }
    }
```

onChildAdded never returns, no data found.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What location does `ref` point to, `results`?

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Started working after adding following to `rules` in Firebase Console

```
"results": {
  ".indexOn": ["selfapi", "title"]
}
```